# Is the following usage of "neither" correct?

Tags: word-usage

> Who had started the washing machine?
>
> A thief?
>
> No, one wouldn't barge into her apartment just to do her laundry.
>
> Could it be John?
>
> **Neither**. He would have called her before coming here.

Is the usage of neither correct here? Why or why not?

Comment: Your use of ***Neither*** there is incorrect. One colloquially "valid" alternative would be ***Not John either***. Which itself is effectively short for ***No, it could not be John either***, but I don't think there are any idiomatically acceptable one- or two-word shortened responses featuring ***either*** or ***neither*** for your cited context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I thought exactly the same, while I was looking at the one word response. Then I took a look into the Cambridge Dictionary online (see my answer below) and there were such answers available. Therefore such one word replies should be valid, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Jochen: There's a world of different between ***Neither*** as a one-word response to a "false binary choice" question like *Do you want tea or coffee,* and OP's cited context where the second of a potentially limitless number of options is being rejected. For OP's exact context, you'd have to explicitly identify the "target" of ***neither*** in the response, since they're not ***both*** referenced in the specific utterance to which you're responding. I think your answer below confuses the issue by citing a context that doesn't match the one being asked about, in that crucial respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either)

> In speaking, we can use neither on its own in replies when we are
>   referring to two things that have already been mentioned:
>
> ```
> A:
>
> Mike, which would you prefer, tea or coffee?
> B:
>
> Neither thanks. I’ve just had a coffee.
> ```

In my opinion your question offers only one option, because the former question, which was related to the thief, was already answered. Therefore I would replace 'neither'.

*NOTE: I am neither a native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help.*